# Creating non-comparable versions of a type in F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I use Guids and strings to serve as keys in my data structure. In C#, I have spent many (accumulated) hours wondering why no event came through with the id I was looking for when the id was an OrderId and I was matching it with a ContractId. What I want to do is to prevent this entire class of error.

Imagine I have a contract with the following underlying data types:

```
type Contract = { Schedule : Guid; TickTable : Guid; Price : float; Quantity : float }
```

Now I have two problems:

```
let contract =
    { Schedule = Guid.Empty; TickTable = Guid.Empty; Price = 0.; Quantity = 0. }
contract.Schedule = contract.TickTable;; // true - ugh
contract.Price = contract.Quantity;; // true - ugh
```

I can fix one problem like this:

```
[<Measure>] type dollars
[<Measure>] type volume
type Contract =
    { Schedule : Guid; TickTable : Guid;
      Price : float<dollars>; Quantity : float<volume> }
```

Now we have:

```
let contract =
    { Schedule = Guid.Empty; TickTable = Guid.Empty;
      Price = 0.<dollars>; Quantity = 0.<volume> }
contract.Schedule = contract.TickTable;; // true - ugh
contract.Price = contract.Quantity;; // type mismatch - yay
```

Is there a way I can decorate the Guids so I get a type mismatch? I only really want to impact compile-time - ideally the compiled code would be the same, as in units of measure.

I know I can do the following, but it seems ugly and I would expect it causes run-time impact:

```
[<Measure>] type dollars
[<Measure>] type volume
type ScheduleId = ScheduleKey of Guid
type TickTableId = TickTableKey of Guid
type Contract =
    { Schedule : ScheduleId; TickTable : TickTableId;
      Price : float<dollars>; Quantity : float<volume> }

let contract =
    { Schedule = ScheduleKey Guid.Empty; TickTable = TickTableKey Guid.Empty;
      Price = 0.<dollars>; Quantity = 0.<volume> }
contract.Schedule = contract.TickTable;; // type error - yay
contract.Price = contract.Quantity;; // type mismatch - yay
```

Comment: The solution you have is reasonably good - I don't think the runtime impact will be too bad.

Comment: @JohnPalmer : It's effectively turning the `Guid`s from value types into reference types, and could cause noticeable GC churn with lots of records. I wish it were possible to make a DU compile as a struct... :-[

Comment: Instead of a DU, could wrap the ids in dedicated struct types

Comment: latkin's suggestion sounds like the way to go. You could also use that approach to address that type of problem in C#.

Comment: Unless you actually have a profile (and/or are demonstrably not IO-bound), the fact that a DU based approach constrains construction whereas a struct can be default-initialized with `Guid.Empty` (== all zeros) and you can't impse a mandatory default ctor (as one can't in C# due to intrinsic .NEt limitations)

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap any type to have units, even generically, by writing a type with a `[<Measure>]` type argument. Also, as latkin hinted in the comments, using a [struct (which is allocated in place, not as a new object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx) would save extra allocation and indirection.

Generic unit-of-measure aware wrapper:

```
type [<Struct>] UnitAware<'T, [<Measure>] 'u> =
    val Raw : 'T
    new (raw) = { Raw = raw }

let withUnit<[<Measure>] 'u> a = UnitAware<_, 'u>(a)
```

This way, arbitrary types can be given a unit-of-measure aware value type wrapper, simply wrapping via `withUnit<myUnit>` and unwrapping with `.Raw`:

```
let a = 146L |> withUnit<dollars>
let b = 146L |> withUnit<volume>

a = b // Type mismatch.
```

Due to structural comparison, two struct wrappers with the same units and with equal contents will also be equal. As with other unit-of-measure usage, the additional type safety is lost at run-time: `box a = box b` is true, just like `box 1.<dollars> = box 1.<volumes>`.